# Ben Kamens jQuery Menu Aim: Sub menu wont reappear after it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

Looking at Ben Kemens [jquery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim), I stumbled upon an example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/mattweb/pen/pkvlh).

This ([codepen](https://codepen.io/mattweb/pen/pkvlh)) works and allows the user time to pass from the main menu to the sub menu BUT if you move away from the menu completely the submenu still keeps showing i.e. it (the submenu) won't go away (display:none).

So, I recreated the same example at codepen on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8m6dxqo/) and changed the Javascript

from:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('a.hover').removeClass('hover');
    $('.popover').css('display', 'none');
}
```

to:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('a.hover').removeClass('hover');
    $('.nav ul ul').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Now, if you click anywhere on the web page, apart from the menu/sub menu, the sub menu disappears as it should.

Problem: The sub menu won't reappear if you hover the main menu again.

How do I solve this?

Edit: Is there an alternate jQuery / Javascript to jquery-menu aim?.

Comment: you are adding a hover class on a click it seems wrong to me

Comment: If i remove the hover class, the main menu would still be on a hover state, that is the background color of hover state stays while the sub menu disappears, I tried it but hover isn't what I am looking at.

Comment: you are removing the hover class entirely therefore it wont work ever again. this can be achieved by just using css. :focus and :hover. there is no need for js at all.

Comment: @JoeLloyd, can you please update the JsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want needs `enter` and `exit` instead of `activate` and `deactivate`.

Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim)?

Here is [your Fiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/9yq99bgq/).

```
$menu.menuAim({
  enter: activateSubmenu,
  exit: deactivateSubmenu
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The moment you try to move your mouse from the main menu "1" to the submenu "7" the sub menu disappears. Please check.

Comment: That is because you are exiting the menu. You could use a timeout in the exit function so the menu would close a couple ms after an exit... Letting you the time to go from 1 to 7. I updated the Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you ... Sorry I did not read the documentation but I should have. Thank you again.